# Django: How can I use variable defined in the other .py file?

Tags: python, django, function, view, arguments

I would like to use below x as variable in function get_price() in the other file plots.py.

**views.py**

```
class ScatterView(TemplateView) :
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = SampleForm() 
        x = request.GET.get('x')
        context['calculated_x'] = plots.get_price()
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**plot.py**

```
def get_price():
    input_x = x + 1
    return input_x
```

But it doesn't work.
How shall I describe the function for this purpose?
The point is, I need to use the returned value for template later via views.py.

Comment: You need to pass that ```x``` variable to ```get_price(x)``` function and process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass it? Change your code to something like this:

```
def get_price(x):
    input_x = x + 1
    return input_x
```

Import it into class like this:

```
import plots
```

Add it to your code like this:

```
class ScatterView(TemplateView) :
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = SampleForm() 
        x = request.GET.get('x')
        context['calculated_x'] = plots.get_price(x)
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks both gens, I tried but then there is a error code as below

Comment: ValueError at /simulator/
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/simulator/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: In fact I do some machine learning calculation at get_price() with sklearn

Comment: Exception Location: /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite, line 56
Python Executable: /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path: 
['/Users/user/Desktop/Django/price_simulator',
 '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-

Comment: When I give fixed value, it's no problem, the template appears. If no value, looks like  it can't show the template correctly due to the fact that my calculation makes error?

Comment: I am not at all familiar with sklearn. You are probably going to want to make a new question as that is probably not a Django problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass x to get_price(x) in plot.py

**views.py**

```
import plot.ply as plots
class ScatterView(TemplateView) :
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = SampleForm() 
        x = request.GET.get('x')
        context['calculated_x'] = plots.get_price(x)
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**plot.py**

```
    def get_price(x):
        input_x = x + 1
        return input_x
```